# prisma - getting environment variable not found error message when running graphql query

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I am getting this error message from prisma when I am running the GraphQL query.

```
Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.\n  -->  schema.prisma:6\n   | \n 5 |   provider = \"postgresql\"\n 6 |   url      = env(\"DATABASE_URL\")\n   | \n\nValidation Error Count: 1",
```

At first, I didn't have the .env file in any of my project folders, then I added it with the link to the database url, still not working.
Here is the folder structure:

[image: The folder structure: in the root, there's node_modules, prisma and src folders, .env, .gitignore and package.json files. Inside prisma, there's a migrations folder and a schema.prisma file.]

This is what I have inside my `.env` file looks like -

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:mypassword@db.pqtgawtgpfhpqxpgidrn.supabase.co:5432/postgres"
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If anybody running into this issue, just run `npx prisma generate`. This will re-establish the link between schema.prisma and .env file.

Comment: For me it turned out that I had `DATABASE_URL="my value` and had forgotten the closing double-quote! So the value wasn't "there" because `dotenv` wasn't able to parse it correctly because of a mistake on my part.

Comment: If you are a next.js user, then see the answers below

Comment: for me, it's not working on next because I'm running the command in another folder different than the root project. It works perfectly running `npx prisma generate` in the correct path.

Comment: @aproximation env values don't need to be quoted

Answer (score 44):

I had this issue in my NextJs project. after changing the .env.local file to .env everything worked.

Answer (score 43):

In my case I wanted to run Prisma Studio with NextJS that stores all environment variables in `.env.local`, so I need to load the file first.

```
npm install -g dotenv-cli
```

```
dotenv -e .env.local -- npx prisma studio
```

Here is a link to the official [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables/managing-env-files-and-setting-variables#manage-env-files-manually) on how to load `.env` files manualy.

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful

I added `"migrate": "dotenv -e .env.local npx prisma migrate dev"` to the scripts in my package.json file as well.

Comment: thanks @fotoflo, I guess adding scripts in package.json file makes it super easy.

Comment: The best answer for my case, updating the answer with packege.json commands will be perfect

Answer (score 1):

In my case I encountered a weird problem with the .env file itself, I created the file using Powershell's echo. Apparently, manually creating it in Vscode solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Others like me (new to Prisma, following the Remix.run jokes-app tutorial) might be relieved to learn it's not just you: there was a regression in Prisma 3.9.0, fixed in 3.9.1 in early Feb 2022. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11570

"prisma db pull doesn't read .env file and errors with Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL"

Answer (score 0):

If you try with a schema completed and an empty db, you have this error. Try "prisma db push" first and after verify with "prisma studio".

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a monorepo, and found that my turbo rollup task didn't allow me to pass in flags. My work around was to modify my `package.json` by copying the `.env` to the same directory as `schema.prisma` file by adding a new command to hard reload with the flag I needed. I ended up adding this to my `package.json`

```
{
 ...
 "scripts": {
   ...
   "db-push:hard": "cp .env prisma/.env && yarn prisma db push --accept-data-loss",
   ...
 },
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me
I have the same issue I just ran npx prisma db push then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows just try to rename .env.local to .env
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because i was using '@prisma/client/edge'

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client/edge'
```

but actually, we need to use @prisma/client

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where your migrations exist and then run the command

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name name_of_migration_file
```